# Binding User Control from second lib project not work - wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

My task: I want to bind textbox and button.

Although I found many topics about it I cannot manage my problem.
I have project: Client with WPF application **WITH DEFAULT XAML no BINDING**, which takes context from MenuWindow project, which is library. Inside MenuWindow project I have User Control WPF called: MenuProgram.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MenuWindow.MenuProgram"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MenuWindow"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="550" d:DesignWidth="780">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:MenuViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid Background="#FF6F6FA4">
    <Label x:Name="lblTitle" Content="GUI Export Revit Data" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="277,31,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="50" Width="258" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblPrtdPath" Content="File prtd path" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="200,176,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblXmlPath1" Content="File xml path1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="200,222,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblXmlPath2" Content="File xml path2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="200,266,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="tbxPrtd" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="302,176,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="268" Text="{Binding PrtdFilePath}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="tbxXml1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="302,222,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="268" Text="{Binding XmlFilePath1}"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="tbxXml2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="302,266,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="268" Text="{Binding XmlFilePath2}"/>
    <Button x:Name="SayHi" Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="302,450,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="174" Height="84" FontSize="22" Command="{Binding SayHi}" />
    <Button x:Name="btnAbout" Content="About" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="705,496,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="55" Height="38" Command="{Binding SayHi}"/>
</Grid>
```

so I have

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
<mv:MenuViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

and with textBoxs or button I want to use binding.

in codeBehind this User Control there is nothing but default initialization. 
In Project Menu there are: 
MenuArguments.cs with mapping:

```
public string PrtdFilePath { get; set; }
public string XmlFilePath1 { get; set; }
public string XmlFilePath2 { get; set; }
```

RelayCommand:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
namespace MenuWindow
{
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Func<Boolean> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action _execute;

    public RelayCommand(Action execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action execute, Func<Boolean> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            if (_canExecute != null)
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            if (_canExecute != null)
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }

    public Boolean CanExecute(Object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute();
    }

    public void Execute(Object parameter)
    {
        _execute();
    }
}
}
```

and MenuViewModel.cs

```
namespace MenuWindow
{
public class MenuViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string gowno;
    public MenuArguments _menuArgumenty;
    public string PrtdFilePath
    {
        get { return _menuArgumenty.PrtdFilePath; }
        set
        {
            _menuArgumenty.PrtdFilePath = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PrtdFilePath");
        }
    }
    public string XmlFilePath1
    {
        get { return _menuArgumenty.XmlFilePath1; }
        set
        {
            _menuArgumenty.XmlFilePath1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("XmlFilePath1");
        }
    }
    public string XmlFilePath2
    {
        get { return _menuArgumenty.XmlFilePath2; }
        set
        {
            _menuArgumenty.XmlFilePath2 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("XmlFilePath2");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public MenuViewModel()
    {
        _menuArgumenty = new MenuArguments();
    }
    public ICommand SayHi
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(SayHiExcute, CanSayHiExcute);
        }
    }

    private void SayHiExcute()
    {
        if (!MenuArgumentsExists(_menuArgumenty))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Hi {0} {1}!", _menuArgumenty.PrtdFilePath, _menuArgumenty.XmlFilePath1));
            SavePerosn(_menuArgumenty);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Hey {0} {1}, you exists in our database!", _menuArgumenty.PrtdFilePath, _menuArgumenty.XmlFilePath1));
        }
    }

    private void SavePerosn(MenuArguments _menuArgumenty)
    {
        //Some Database Logic
    }

    private bool CanSayHiExcute()
    {
        return !MenuArgumentsExists(_menuArgumenty);
    }

    private bool MenuArgumentsExists(MenuArguments _menuArgumenty)
    {
        //Some logic
        return false;
    }

}
}
```

When I start program debuger goes through binding properties. After window appears there is no reaction from binding. What do I do wrong? Please help me.

BR,
student Cenarius

**Thanks for comments, answers to your comments:**

**@tabby** - I want to bind textBoxes: PrtdFilePath, XmlFilePath1, XmlFilePath1 and button SayHi

**@maulik kansara** - You are right, I was trying some another methods and I didnt remove code. It should be only version with local.

**@grek40** - My example works for one-project in solution for Window not for UserControl which is set in another project. Here is picture: 
[image]

**@mm8** - I expected by puting data ino textBoxes or clicking button to see breakpoint in:

```
        public string PrtdFilePath
    {
        get { return _menuArgumenty.PrtdFilePath; }
        set
        {
            _menuArgumenty.PrtdFilePath = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PrtdFilePath");
        }
    }
```

Finally, I think that code in XAML is problem. I was reading about parent-child relations with finding binding/viewmodel/path but I am confused and I dont know how to solve it. Please help me thanks You for all comments.

@grek40 here is Code in Main APP WPF, I add context from my MenuWindow.
This MainWindow WPF APP has default XAML.

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        menuProgram = new MenuProgram();//User Control
        sw = new SharedWindow();//WPF window
        this.Close();
        sw.Content = menuProgram.Content;// here I set context
        sw.ShowDialog();
    }
```

and XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Client.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Client"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

Whole code with Your change:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private SharedWindow sw;
    private MenuProgram menuProgram;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        menuProgram = new MenuProgram();
        SetForContext();
    }
    private void SetForContext()
    {
        sw = new SharedWindow();
        this.Close();
        sw.Content = menuProgram;
        sw.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: Do you get any binding messages in the output tab in Visual Studio?

Comment: @Mark I dont get anything as error, is it way to see it? I am junior developer I dont fell being expert from VS2017

Comment: My code is kind of example and it works for normal Window (WPF) applicaton. Potential problem is because of this diffrence: in my main WPF I launch: this.Content = menuProgram.Content; this.ShowDialog() and there are also some diffrences in xaml. I almost sure that xaml is problem and there is somewhere problem there.

Comment: how you are assigning values to your property?

Comment: One problem figured out. I don't think that it is related to your question but you should correct it.  common namespace referenced twice 
    (1)xmlns:mv="clr-namespace:MenuWindow"    
    (2) xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MenuWindow"

Comment: Where and how are you expecting the "reaction from binding"? And what happens?

Comment: @tabby, maulik kansara, grek40, mm8  Thanks for comments, I replied in my main post.

Comment: @grek40 Thanks for notice, I put extra link to this photo and I updated my post: https://images84.fotosik.pl/957/a4870d907fbf8052.png

Comment: Can you please show the code/xaml where you use the UserControl? Also, please make sure that you don't re-set the `DataContext` from some other source.

Comment: @grek40  Thanks for repley, code is posted as first part of code; (ctr + f "UserControl"). What do you mean re-set DataContext? I just set Context from this MenuWindow to SharedWindow.Context and I launch: ShowDialog(). I dont have extra methods for Data Context. In XAML I have: <UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:MenuViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext> and example: ...Text="{Binding PrtdFilePath}"/>

Comment: *"I just set Context from this MenuWindow to SharedWindow.Context and I launch: ShowDialog()"* That's the part I would like to see as code, because I don't 100% understand your description and there is potential for problems. Basically, there is `Content` and `DataContext`, I don't know about any `Context` property. I have a pretty good idea what goes wrong most likely, but I can't be sure without actually seeing the code

Comment: @grek40 thanks for help, Updated post

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `UserControl` as window `Content`, not the `Content` of `UserControl`:

```
sw.Content = menuProgram;// here I set context
/* Bad: sw.Content = menuProgram.Content; */
```

Your `DataContext` is assigned to the `UserControl` itself, so if you move the `Content` tree to a different `Parent`, it will no longer have its old `DataContext`.

Comment: Thanks for post when I set your line I get error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Window must be the root of the tree. Cannot add Window as a child of Visual.' I add whole to my Post.

Comment: Are you sure that `MenuWindow.MenuProgram` is inheriting `UserControl`?

Comment: @Cenarius Generally I'm slightly worried because you close your `MainWindow` when you start showing the dialog. There is a whole bunch of side-issues that *might* cause some problems. Generally, setting a UserControl as Content of a Window should work.

Comment: public partial class MainWindow : Window, public partial class SharedWindow : Window, public partial class MenuProgram : UserControl. I removed this.Close() and it's the same error.

Comment: @Cenarius Maybe we can handle the side-issue first... why are you creating a new window in the MainWindow Contructor and closing the MainWindow right away? Together with `Application.ShutdownMode="OnMainWindowClose"` this should be a desaster recipe. Maybe you just want to execute some startup code by removing `Application.StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` and adding `Application.Startup="My_Startup_Method"`? (look for `App.xaml` / `App.xaml.cs`)

Comment: Mayby this closing is bad idea, I thought to remove main window which is for me core.
As I showed on screen I would like to create one window WPF instead of many to do Application. Other "windows" I mean User Control wll be linked. I think it's better to have one window and .DLL to manage it in build or whatever. That's my concept to create app. I dont have experience so much so I wanted to have a core MainWindow and a SharedWindow which will get User Controls. If you have another concept for that I can use it. I just need simple example for that, then I will know how to extend it.

Comment: @Cenarius sorry, but Stackoverflow is not really suited to discuss large scale design choices. You should consider finding a dedicated programmers community forum or something similar. Stackoverflow is meant to answer specific questions - in your case, the DataContext was lost because you did the wrong assignment and generally, assigning the whole UserControl to a Content property should fix your problem. The commented Exception can't really appear from the setup in question, so there is something different going wrong, which would turn the question into a debugging task...

Comment: Thanks for help, instead of libs I will do WPF projects, which works. I do important project for my studies. It must just work and if possible it could be written well. Thanks for time and patience Cenarius :)